# Codility PermCheck My Solution for Two Elements

Tags: java, arrays

For the following codility task my solution is 100% correct from the Performance point of view and 80% from the correctness point of view. My Solution is failing for two elements but I have tested it with different values (two elements) and I am getting required output. Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

**Codility Task link**
https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/perm_check/

My Code:

```
 import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        if(A.length == 1){
                if(A[0] != 1)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
                Arrays.sort(A);
                for(int i =1; i<A.length; i++){                 
                    if(A[i] - A[i-1] != 1){
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            return 1;
    }
}
```

**Failing Test Case:**

```
double  two elements ✘WRONG ANSWER  got 1 expected 0
1. 0.004 s OK
2. 0.004 s OK
3. 0.004 s WRONG ANSWER,  got 1 expected 0
4. 0.004 s OK
```

Comment: Interesting that your complexity is more than O(N) because of sort()

Comment: Codility evaluated it like this.   **Detected time complexity:
O(N) or O(N * log(N))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from that your solution isn’t O(N), you accept any array with sequential numbers even if the sequence doesn’t start at 1. Test with [3, 4] or [7, 9, 8].

With your current solution you want to check if A[i]==i+1

You need a different approach to get to O(N).

Comment: Yes, I missed it, Now I have just added a condition for this and its working fine 100%  correct. "public static int solution(int[] A){
   if(A.length == 1){
    if(A[0] != 1)
     return 0;
    else
     return 1;
   }
    Arrays.sort(A);
    for(int i =1; i<A.length; i++){  
     if(A[0] != 1)
      return 0;
     if(A[i] - A[i-1] != 1){
      return 0;
     }
    }
   return 1;"

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.

A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once, and only once.

For example, array A such that:

```
 A[0] = 4
 A[1] = 1
 A[2] = 3
 A[3] = 2
```

is a permutation, but array A such that:

```
 A[0] = 4
 A[1] = 1
 A[2] = 3
```

is not a permutation, because value 2 is missing.

The goal is to check whether array A is a permutation.

Write a function:

int solution(NSMutableArray *A);
 that, given an array A, returns 1 if array A is a permutation and 0 if it is not.

For example, given array A such that:

```
 A[0] = 4
 A[1] = 1
 A[2] = 3
 A[3] = 2
```

the function should return 1.

Given array A such that:

```
 A[0] = 4
 A[1] = 1
 A[2] = 3
```

the function should return 0.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
 each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].

**OBJECTIVE-C SOLUTION O(N)**

**Results given by Codility**

Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: 100%

**Time Complexity**

The worst case time complexity is O(N) or O(N * log(N))

[Xcode Solution Here](https://github.com/jmanuelmosso/CSWarmingInterview/blob/master/CSWarmingInterview/CodilityChallenges/CountingElements/PermCheck.m)

```
+(int)solution:(NSMutableArray*)array {

    /******** Algorithm Explanation  ********/
    // STEP 1
    //       Check for edge cases - when the array is empty [], we should return 0
    // STEP 2
    //      Generate NSSet from the Array in oder to eliminate possible duplicates
    //      NSSet also has better performance on search elements
    // STEP 3
    //      Implement a loop taking in consideration:
    //          So, to be a permutation, in the Array we MUST have N => (1,2,3...n)
    //          they don't need to be necessary ordered, but should conntain all the elemements from 1 to n
    //
    // STEP 4
    //      Look for the current target in the SET
    //      If the target does't exist, that means  is not a permutation
    //      Break the loop.


    // STEP 1
    int isPermutation = 1;
    int n = (int)[array count];
    if (n==0) {
        isPermutation=0;
    }
    else {
        // STEP 2
        NSSet *elements = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
        int  target = 1;
        // STEP 3
        while (target <= n) {
            // STEP 4
            if (![elements containsObject:@(target)]) {
                isPermutation = 0;
                return isPermutation;
            }
            target++;
        }

    }
    return isPermutation;
}
```